# Leave someone out. Discard somebody out. What is wrong with this sentence can someone help

Tags: phrases

In a demo session a demo students said the sentence. Sometimes you just have to **discard somebody out.** I didn't know how to fix it but I know he meant sometimes you have to leave somebody out. But how would I correct this

Comment: Because *leave out* is a phrasal verb, as is *throw out*, but *discard out* isn't. If you want a high-level justification: the idea of *out* is already embedded in *discard*, both literally in the sense of the physical movements required to remove a card from one's hand, and metaphorically in sense tht once you *discard* something, you've dispensed with it, for once and always. By contrast, one can *leave* his child with the sitter and yet return to it later, or *leave* the room and then re-enter. Similarly, one can throw [a ball] *up*, *down*, *in*, etc, & also *out*. Qualification is needed.